# how to export a mysql data table search query into csv using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, export-to-csv

how to export a mysql data table search query into csv using php?

hear is query

```
if ($_REQUEST["startfrom"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["end"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT ECRNo,SalesDate,TimeSold,AmountDue,OutletName,ProductCode,Category,MealType,SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity1,SUM(NetPrice) AS NetPrice1 FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE SalesDate BETWEEN '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"])."'And'".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["end"])."'".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode.$search_groupby;
} else if ($_REQUEST["startfrom"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT ECRNo,SalesDate,TimeSold,AmountDue,SalesDate,OutletName,ProductCode,Category,MealType,SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity1,SUM(NetPrice) AS NetPrice1 FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE SalesDate >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"])."'".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode.$search_groupby;
} else if ($_REQUEST["end"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT ECRNo,SalesDate,TimeSold,SalesDate,AmountDue,OutletName,ProductCode,Category,MealType,SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity1,SUM(NetPrice) AS NetPrice1 FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE SalesDate <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["end"])."'".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode.$search_groupby;
}else {
    $sql = "SELECT ECRNo,SalesDate,TimeSold,SalesDate,AmountDue,OutletName,ProductCode,Category,MealType,SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity1,SUM(NetPrice) AS NetPrice1 FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE ECRNo>0 ".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode.$search_groupby;
}
```

how do i export its query result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From
>   http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/fileName.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 6):

All good answers here but if you want to do it using PHP, here is another option:

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

The $list array would be your results from the DB.

Taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Answer (score 2):

This is work perfectly, Please try this...

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "Database/business.sql"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
FROM `business`
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql feature:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv'
```

. I think it should work